# Find Adjoint of $L = p(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + r(x) \frac{d}{dx} + q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators

> Suppose that
>   \begin{align*}
>   L &= p(x) \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + r(x) \frac{d}{dx} + q(x) \\
> \end{align*}
>   Consider
>   \begin{align*}
>   \int_a^b vL(u) \, dx \\
> \end{align*}
>   By repeated integration by parts, determine the adjoint operator $L^*$ such that
>   \begin{align*}
>   \int_a^b \left[ uL^*(v) - vL(u) \right] &= \left. H(x) \right|_a^b \\
> \end{align*}
>   What is $H(x)$? Under what conditions does $L=L^*$, the self-adjoint case?
>
> *Hint*: Show that
>   \begin{align*}
>   L^* &= p \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \left( 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \frac{d}{dx} + \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} + q \right) \\
> \end{align*}
>   The given answer that I must find is:
>   \begin{align*}
>   H(x) &= p \left( u \frac{dv}{dx} - v \frac{du}{dx} \right) + uv \left( \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \\
> \end{align*}

I'm not sure how to calculate the $L^*$ given in the hint, I obviously know integration by parts, but I don't see how that would be used here, I don't see how to calculate $H(x)$ when we have $L^*$.

Once we have $L^*$, I can identify the self-adjoint conditions where $L = L^*$:

\begin{align*}
  p \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + r \frac{d}{dx} + q &= p \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + \left( 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \frac{d}{dx} + \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} + q \right) \\
  r \frac{d}{dx} + q &= \left( 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \frac{d}{dx} + \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} + q \right) \\
\end{align*}

which would mean that

\begin{align*}
  r(x) &= 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r(x) \\
  \frac{dp}{dx} &= r(x) \\
  p(x) &= \int r(x) \, dx \\
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
  q &= \frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx}(x) + q \\
  \frac{d^2p}{dx^2} &= \frac{dr}{dx}(x) \\
  \frac{dp}{dx} &= r(x) + c \\
  p(x) &= \int \left( r(x) + c \right) \, dx \\
\end{align*}

Since both expressions must be true, the constant in the second expression can be eliminated. We can conclude that $L = L^*$ if and only if $p(x) = \int r(x) \, dx$

I try to calculate $u L^*(v) - v L(u)$ but this doesn't seem useful:

\begin{align*}
  u L^*(v) &= u p \frac{d^2v}{dx^2} + u \left( 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \frac{dv}{dx} + u \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} + q \right) v \\
  v L(u) &= v p \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + v r \frac{du}{dx} + v q u \\
  u L^*(v) - v L(u) &= p \left( u \frac{d^2v}{dx^2} - v \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \right) + u \left( 2 \frac{dp}{dx} - r \right) \frac{dv}{dx} + u \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} \right) v - v r \frac{du}{dx} \\
  &= p \left( u \frac{d^2v}{dx^2} - v \frac{d^2u}{dx^2} \right) + 2 u \frac{dp}{dx} \frac{dv}{dx} + u \left(\frac{d^2p}{dx^2} - \frac{dr}{dx} \right) v - r \left( u \frac{dv}{dx} + v \frac{du}{dx} \right) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that $r$ is a function of $x$, not a constant. $\frac {dp}{dx} = r$ does not imply that $p(x) = rx + c$. And similarly for the next calculation.

Comment: You are 100% correct and I made that correction. Thank you for that. However, I still don't know how to approach the rest of the problem.